# Creating spring-mvc project using spring 6 with required dependencies

Tags: spring-mvc

I looked into many blogs could not find anything helpful. After all the trial and error, I was able to figure it out, this worked for me

Here are the steps to fallow

- Add the below dependencies. Make sure you are use proper java version. Tomcat 10.1 is required

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

- Create configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.***.***"})
public class AppConfiguration  {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
    
}
```

- Initialise the DispatcherServlet

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebInetialiser extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {AppConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

jakarta.servlet dependency is must required.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is about?